# Dropkick is not populating my programmatically created dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues getting the dropdown to work with a programitcally created select.

My HTML.erb is

```
<select id="ohyes" name="uniselect" tabindex="2">

<option selected="" value="0">Select University of Interest</option>

<% @unis.each do |uni| %>
<option value="<%= uni.id %>"><%= uni.name %></option>
<% end %>

</select>
```

My main .js includes

```
$(document).on("ready page:load", function () {

$('#ohyes').dropkick();
...
});
```

The main box is rendering, the correct select is being produced from the array, however, the dropkick list reamins unpouplated and therefore I see no dropdown when I click on the box.

Update

I am using google maps api to display a map. When the map doesn't load the dropkick dropdown then works.

Comment: you tried with just `$(document).ready(function () {`?

Comment: Yes doesn't work unfortunately.